# iPhone crash randomly when calling a camera?

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, crash

I have tested my app using instrument and it show the following leak.
[image]

When I double click on the CameraVC in the stack trace it refer to the following line into my code.
[image]

this happen when I call the camera, I call it using the following code:-

```
      - (IBAction) getCamera
{
    // set up our camera overlay view   
    // tool bar - handy if you want to be able to exit from the image picker...
    UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 480-44, 320, 44)];

    UIBarButtonItem *spaceItem  = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace  target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
    UIBarButtonItem *spaceItem1  = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace  target:nil action:nil] autorelease];
    UIBarButtonItem *cancelItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel  target:self action:@selector(cancelPickingImag)] autorelease];
    UIBarButtonItem *cameraItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCamera  target:self action:@selector(finishedAugmentedReality)] autorelease]; 

    spaceItem.width  = 2.0;
    spaceItem1.width = 55.0;
    NSArray *items=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spaceItem,cancelItem,spaceItem1,cameraItem,nil];
    [toolBar setItems:items];

    // create the overlay view
    overlayView=[[OverlayView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 300, 320, 480-44)];

    // important - it needs to be transparent so the camera preview shows through!
    overlayView.opaque=NO;
    overlayView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    // parent view for our overlay
    UIView *parentView=[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320, 480)];
    [parentView addSubview:overlayView];
    [parentView addSubview:toolBar];
    [parentView addSubview:lbl];
    [parentView addSubview:overlayGraphicView];

    // configure the image picker with our overlay view
    //UIImagePickerController *picker=[[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
         UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
    {
        imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        // hide the camera controls
        imagePicker.showsCameraControls=NO;

        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        //imagePicker.allowsImageEditing = NO;

        // and put our overlay view in
        imagePicker.cameraOverlayView=parentView;
    }
    else
    {
        imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        imagePicker.delegate = self;
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  (NSString *) kUTTypeImage,
                                  nil];
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;

    }

    [self presentModalViewController:imagePicker animated:YES];

    //Free memory 
    [imagePicker release];//,imagePicker =nil;
    [parentView release], parentView=nil;
    [overlayGraphicView release], overlayGraphicView= nil;
    [lbl release], lbl=nil;
    [overlayView release];//, overlayView =nil;
    [toolBar release], toolBar=nil;
}
```

any help is highly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: @DustinRowland, thank you for replying, I release it in the end of the function.

Comment: I don't release it because I don't use init or alloc.

Comment: `arrayWithObjects` is a convenience method, it actually does `[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:]`

Comment: @DustinRowland, when I release it and using analyze to build the system it give a potential leak.

Comment: Try using zombies and watching the retain counts of your variables

Comment: @DustinRowland -- Actually, arrayWithObjects returns an autoreleased object.

Comment: @DustinRowland, I enabled the Zombies and it show me this [CALayer retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xb22a4b0 into the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parentView` is being created with `[alloc [init...]]`, meaning it's `retain`ed.  Then you assign it to the `cameraOverlayView` property of `imagePicker`, meaning it gets `retain`ed again.  You need to `release` it after you do that assignment.

(This is almost certainly the cause of the "leak", but would not cause a "crash".  You say you're having a crash but don't describe that at all.)

Comment: It looks like he's getting a crash from a zombie.

Comment: @Hot Licks, thank you for replying, the crash happen after the I access the camera, actually after I take 6 picture it is crash. Release the parentView don't solve the problem.

Comment: @Khattab -- You've had several good hints here.  Show some initiative.

Comment: Thanks for all hints that have helped me to solve this question, Thanks for all